# arguments in sqlite3_open()

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am using sqlite3 with iOS for the first time.. in the part where i have to open the connection to the database using the
`sqlite3_open(const char *filename, sqlite3 **ppDb)` function.
I was going through the following code snippet:

```
    int err = sqlite3_open((databasePath ? [databasePath fileSystemRepresentation] : ":memory:"), &db );
    if(err != SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"error opening!: %d", err);
        return NO;
    }
```

what is `?` for and `:memory:`.. 
here, `databasePath` is an `NSString` that contains the path to the database and `db` is an instance of `sqlite3`.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Try `fmdb` sqlite wrapper to make easy of using sqlite inside your iPhone application.

Comment: You should really use the `sqlite3_open_v2` function. You get better control than with `sqlite3_open`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` followed by `:` is called "Ternary operator".

The line `(databasePath ? [databasePath fileSystemRepresentation] : ":memory:")` means:

If `databasePath` is true, use `[databasePath fileSystemRepresentation]`, else use `":memory:"`.

The line is the one-liner edition of the following:

```
if(databasePath) {
  return [databasePath fileSystemRepresentation];
} else {
  return ":memory:";
}
```

`:memory:` is In-Memory Database. See the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

`?:` is the ternary operator, explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a#C).

In this particular instance it's a shortcut way of writing:

```
int err;
if (databasePath) 
    err = sqlite3_open([databasePath fileSystemRepresentation], &db);
else
    err = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
if (err != SQLITE_OK) {
```

But, as I'm sure you'll agree, much more concise.

Comment: if(databasePath) will return TRUE when it contains some value (any NSString object). It should'n't be equal to NULL in order to return true.. right???

Comment: Yes; a better test is `if ([databasePath length])` which will be `NO` if either the `databasePath == nil` or it's empty.